# extjs: get check value from radio button

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using radiogroup Yes and No. I want the click value to be sent to server. How to achieve it?

My COde:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'Striping',
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    columns: [50, 100],
    items: [{
        boxLabel: 'Yes',
        name: 'rb',
        id: 'stYes',
        /*checked: true,*/
        inputValue: '1',
        listeners: {
            click: function () {
                alert("Click 2!");
            }
        }

    }, {
        boxLabel: 'No',
        name: 'rb',
        id: 'stNo',
        inputValue: '2',
        listeners: {
            click: function () {
                alert("Click 2!");
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: there isn't `click` event on radio, try `check` event. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.Radio-event-check

Comment: Use `defaults: {name: 'rb'}` on the radiogroup to automatically have all radios within the group act like a group.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this will work, I can't test this atm.
Click won't word for radio buttons, you need to use the change event. Also you better place the listener on your group. Then you don't have to define a listener for each button in your group.

Note: be careful with giving id's to components, use itemId, or name instead.

```
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Striping',
        xtype:'radiogroup',
        columns: [50, 100],
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Yes',
            name: 'rb',
            id: 'stYes',
            /*checked: true,*/
            inputValue: '1'

        }, 
        {
            boxLabel: 'No',
            name: 'rb',
            id: 'stNo',
            inputValue: '2'
        }],
        listeners: {
            change: function( radiogroup, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) {
                alert(newValue.rb);
            }
        }
    }
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/cpLvK/7/

Comment: new value is an object so you can get value by 
newValue.inputValue

Comment: not a working solution. both the comment above and solution as well

Comment: Actually it is a working solutions... http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/cpLvK/7/  newValue is an object. newValue.rb will show you the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

`.individual` will return `inputValue` which you set in radiogroup items.

```
 listeners: {
        change: function( radiogroup, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) {
            alert(newValue.individual);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Solved this issue without adding 'name' config in RadioButtons
to get the value I just used :

```
change : function(radioButton,newValue,oldValue){

var newVal = Object.keys(newValue).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
var value = newVal[0];
console.log(value)

}
```